# Forbidden: You don't have permission to access / on this server, LAMP Server on Fedora 22

Tags: apache, laravel, fedora, lamp

I have been installed LAMP server on Fedora 22 , but when i need access 
my server localhost/myapp/public , I see this error

```
Forbidden
  You don't have permission to access /myapp/public/ on this server.
  Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
```

How I can solve this isuue, I think this issue may be solving by modify 
httpd.conf file ,but i don't know How do it , i am use apache2

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a corresponding error_log acess referencing an on-disk htaccess file.

If you use the "itk" MPM, it's likely an ITK problem. Otherwise, make sure all directories between root and your content directory are world readable and world executable, and that any .htaccess files are readable by the servers ID (www-data, apache, etc)

Comment: thanks sir covener , in fact i don't know more about apache server , i'm not server admin , and i'm working on fedora workstation , you can say that i`m just user , if you can explain to me more i will be grateful to you
thank you for help